# Swipe jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

somebody know how to create a function for "swipeRight" event using jquery? You know a plug-in to do this?

```
$(function(){       
    $(".container").swipeRight(function(){
        ***simple add class funcctions***
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what `swipeRight` will do? what do want to achieve? do you want to listen swipe right event. How it will happen with container. Please add more detail.

Comment: Are you wanting a  function or event? are you creating a swipeRight function or trying to bind to the swipeRight event??

Comment: I want to change an element class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a plugin, but the jQuery Mobile library already has swipe event listeners (with addClass example in the link).

https://api.jquerymobile.com/swiperight/